# oracleConnection.createARRAY not working with WebLogic Data Source Connection

Tags: java, oracle, struct, weblogic, jndi

So, I was using a datasource which was defined in Spring, which was working fine. Then I updated my project to take the datasource from the Weblogic server which the application is running on. This too, works fine for most calls to the database, except for one scenario - This scenario is involved sending a list of objects to the database, based on database types which are defined in Java by using Structs.

The full method is:

```
@Override
public List<String> saveAllocation(String originalId, List<Parcel> parcels) throws SQLException {

    if(originalId == null || parcels == null) {
        return null;
    }

    List<String> results = null;

    String result = null;
    String log = null;

    OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection)jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();

        try {

            OracleCallableStatement cs = (OracleCallableStatement) oracleConnection.prepareCall("{ call PACKAGE.Update(?, ?, ?, ?) }");

            Struct[] cpoList = new Struct[parcels.size()];

            for(int i = 0; i < parcels.size(); i++) {
                Object[] obj = new Object[] { parcels.get(i).getParcel_id(), parcels.get(i).getPublicID().toUpperCase() };
                Struct struct = oracleConnection.createStruct("SCHEME_NAME.PARCEL_OBJ", obj);
                cpoList[i] = struct;
            }

            Array array = oracleConnection.createARRAY("SCHEME_NAME.PARCEL_TAB", cpoList);


            cs.setString(1, originalId);
            cs.setArray(2, array);
            cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);

            cs.executeUpdate();

            log = cs.getObject(3).toString();
            result = cs.getObject(4).toString();


            results = new ArrayList<>();

            results.add(result);
            results.add(log);

        } catch(SQLException e) {
            //Log exception
            return results;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //Log exception
            return results;

        } finally {

            if (cs != null) {
                cs.close();
            }
        }

        return results;

    }
}
```

The database objects are defined as:

PARCEL_OBJ

`create or replace TYPE parcel_obj AS OBJECT 
(PARCEL_ID             VARCHAR2(11),
 PUBLIC_ID          VARCHAR2(20));`

PARCEL_TAB

`create or replace TYPE parcel_tab IS TABLE OF parcel_obj;`

The application fails on the line

`Array array = oracleConnection.createARRAY("SCHEME_NAME.PARCEL_TAB", cpoList);`

The exception message is:

`java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Struct_oracle_sql_STRUCT@187>`

My JNDI connection is defined in my application.properties like:

`spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/pio`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have discovered that if I disable Weblogic data type wrapping through the admin console of the weblogic server, then the problem is resolved. Does anyone know if disabling this wrapping is a good/bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/jdbc/jdbc_datasources/DisableWrapping.html) mentions.

> By default, data type objects for Array, Blob, Clob, NClob, Ref,
> SQLXML, and Struct, plus ParameterMetaData and ResultSetMetaData
> objects are wrapped with a WebLogic wrapper.

In some cases setting the wrapping parameter to false can improve significantly the performance and allows the application to use a native driver.

I don't see a problem disabling that option since it is causing the problem when calling objects like `struct` in the first place.